# Accelerometer Jump/Walk/Run Gesture, Which method to use

Tags: android, accelerometer, gesture

It appears I have some choices to make before I dive into gesture recognition.  I'm finding readings on Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) and Hidden Markov Models.  Both of these topics are rather large and will likely involve me sinking lots of time into.

For recognizing something like a jump or walking/running is it even worth using these complex models?  If so is one better than the other for any particular reason?

The usage here involves a phone that is either in your hand or pocket.